# What do two consecutive \usecolortheme statements mean in a beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I was taking a look at a Beamer theme code in: /usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeRochester.sty

It contains code like this:

```
\useoutertheme[width=0pt]{sidebar}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
```

Why are there two consecutive `\usecolortheme` statements here? Wouldn't the second statement override the first statement anyway?

Comment: Both define a different subset of things. While whale is about vegetable colors, orchid is about crayon colours. Have a look at `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamercolorthemeorchid.sty` and `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamercolorthemewhale.sty`

Comment: Or look at the documentation, `whale` is an outer colour theme, changing the appearance of palette colours. `orchid`  is an inner colour theme, most notably changing the color of blocks.

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you like to convert you comments into an answer? I think they summarise it pretty good!

Comment: @samcarter You are more of a beamer expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `orchid` and `whale` are loaded using the same mechanism of `\usecolortheme`, but they define colors for different instances of a beamer slide. Maybe the order of the lines could have been a bit different:

```
\useoutertheme[width=0pt]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
```

`whale`  is an outer color theme, changing the appearance of palette colours. `orchid` on the other hand, is an inner color theme, most notably changing the color of blocks. The beamer documentation explains this in a little more detail.